# Does Kotlin generated byte code affect the method count?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

For example, if I use

```
methodReference = ::method
```

rather than

```
methodReference = { method(it) }
```

decompiled code will contain `getOwner`, `getName`, `getSignature` methods in Java code, due to reflection. Do these methods counted against 64k limit ?

Comment: yes, in they are not removed by proguard/R8

Comment: I know it's really small difference, but does this make passing a lambda more efficient than method referencing ?

Comment: there is no difference at all, the first one will generate an object for the method reference (several methods), the second - the lambda

Comment: Thanks ! If you add an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The methods are counted, only if they are not removed by proguard/R8

An example

```
  fun method(t : Any) {}
  val reference1: KFunction1<Any, Unit> = ::method
  val reference2: (Any) -> Unit = { method(it) }
```

For the `reference1` the bytecode (decompiled to Java) would be:

```java
   @NotNull
   final KFunction reference1 = new Function1((X)this) {
      // $FF: synthetic method
      // $FF: bridge method
      public Object invoke(Object var1) {.. }
      public final void invoke(@NotNull Object p1) {..}
      public final KDeclarationContainer getOwner() {..}
      public final String getName() {..}
      public final String getSignature() {..}
   };
```

for the lambda (or reference2) the equivalent java code is:

```java
   @NotNull
   final Function1 reference2 = (Function1)(new Function1() {
      // $FF: synthetic method
      // $FF: bridge method
      public Object invoke(Object var1) {..}
      public final void invoke(@NotNull Object it) {..}
   });
```

So the difference is 4 +1 for method reference and 1 +1 for lambda, where `+1` comes from the the bridge method `invoke(t:Any)`

Comment: This does not to seem to be a problem anymore. As of writing this, Kotlin 1.6 is out and when decompiling provided example we get the same bytecode in both cases.